# Loop through folder using array to find lastest version (count) with VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, counter

I have attached a code, however, this will only find the files that is present in the folder.
What I want to have is an incremental counter for the files. Thing is that sometimes the version will start something else than 0 or 1, e.g. 3.
`Amesto non AN suppliers TEST W20-3 AN` then I want the next string to be 4.

I am currently using this, but it will only work if 1 is the first, etc.
I am really stuck.

```
' Version check
    Do While Len(Dir(strPath2 & "Amesto non AN suppliers TEST W" & week & "-" & version & "*.cif")) <> 0
        version = version + 1
        strPath = getDirectoryPath & "Amesto non AN suppliers TEST W" & week & "-" & version & " " & UserName & ".cif"
    Loop


Sub loadversion()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Counter As Long

'Create a dynamic array variable, and then declare its initial size
Dim DirectoryListArray() As String
ReDim DirectoryListArray(1000)

'Loop through all the files in the directory by using Dir$ function
MyFile = Dir$("C:\Users\niclas.madsen\Desktop\AP\WAVE3\CIF\*.*")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    DirectoryListArray(Counter) = MyFile
    MyFile = Dir$
    Counter = Counter + 1
Loop

' do something here?!
If MyFile = vbNullString Then

Else

End If 

'Reset the size of the array without losing its values by using Redim Preserve
ReDim Preserve DirectoryListArray(Counter - 1)

For Counter = 0 To UBound(DirectoryListArray)
    'Debug.Print writes the results to the Immediate window (press Ctrl + G to view it)'
    Debug.Print DirectoryListArray(Counter)
Next Counter 
End Sub
```

Comment: seems like thats not the whole code. In what sub is the first loop located? Another question: Does it give you an error if the version don't start with 1?

Comment: Hi @EngJon the first 'version check' is from the sub where I save the file. However, this sub is just a test to see if I can get it to work and then replace that version check. No, right now the array will just list the amount of files in the folder, but not save or doing anything else. The version check will go to the first available value, so if the files that exists is 3 and 4, it will start with 1 :( I want that to be 5. Hope you understand.

Comment: The version check just assumes there's no greater version. If you know that the starting version will never be higher than 4, you could check not only version 1 in your loop but force it to look up to version 4. You can do that in a separate for-loop before the actual loop.

Comment: I don't know how many there will be, it can vary from 1 to 9 (I would say). The thing is that we import this file into the folder, so sometimes we will import version 4 and hence we need to create version 5. So it would be cool, if the macro could automatically recall what the highest number there is found in the folder.

Comment: You can iterate through all files in the folder, cut the first part (name and week), then check character for character until it's not a numeric value anymore, cut from that character on -> you get the version. Then convert those strings to numbers, put them in an array (list) and sort it. That way you will get the highest number

Comment: Could you provide some start help with a code that I can work on? Thanks for your help so far, really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, had no time 'till now. My answer shows a way to get the highest version. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highest version on a filename in your directory, insert the following functions:

```
Function CheckHighestVersion(path As String, cutLettersAtWordBeginning As Integer) As Integer
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim toBeCut As String
    Dim verLength As Integer
    Dim highestVersion As Integer
    highestVersion = 0
    file = Dir(path)

    While (file <> "")
        toBeCut = file
        toBeCut = Mid(toBeCut, cutLettersAtWordBeginning + 1)
        verLength = FindVerLength(toBeCut)
        If verLength = -1 Then
            CheckHighestVersion = 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        toBeCut = Left(toBeCut, verLength)
        If Val(toBeCut) > highestVersion Then
            highestVersion = Val(toBeCut)
        End If
        file = Dir
    Wend
    CheckHighestVersion = highestVersion
End Function

Function FindVerLength(fileName As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(fileName)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(fileName, i, 1)) Then
            If i = 1 Then
                MsgBox "Couldn't obtain the highest version of the files: " & _
                "The first letter of the version is not numeric. The letter is " & Mid(fileName, i, 1) & _
                ". Please use correct amount of letters to be cut at the beginning of the file name."
                FindVerLength = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
            FindVerLength = i - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    FindVerLength = i
End Function
```

Call `CheckHighestVersion` in your Sub. the path is only the directory (e.g. C:\Test\ ), the second parameter is the number of letters you don't need at the beginning of the word. If I counted correctly, that value should be 30+(length of week, week 25 would be 2, week 7 would be 1) in your case. The function returns the highest version contained in that folder.

Comment: Hi @Engjon! Sorry for my late reply, I have been super busy. I have not checked it yet, but do I just call it `CheckHighestVersion(getDirectoryPath, 30)`? And what exactly will it return? Will it return the next available number or the highest number found? Thanks!

Comment: @Niclas Madsen it will return the current highest number

Comment: Thank you very much, works almost perfectly! I managed to change it, so the version will not be the weeks, but the actually version, so I can use `HighestVersion` + 1 to make it work as I desire. Really appreciate it.